# The characters of the groups' representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Determine which of the central functions on $S_3$ is the character and specify this representation

$f_1 : (e, (1,2), (1,3), (2, 3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2))\to(6,-4,-4,-4,0,0)$
$f_2 : (e, (1,2), (1,3), (2, 3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2))\to(6,-4,-4,-4,3,3)$

I'm stuck on this problem and I don't understand how to bring it to a solution. What should be used in this task to select the correct function and how to specify this representation? I understand that character is a trace of representation, but from this definition, I can't come to anything yet.

Comment: Which characters of $S_3$ do you know? Typically (but not necessarily, I haven't checked yet) you need to have a list of the irreducible characters, but may be you can get away with less. Anyway, it is difficult to help you without any information about your background as well as other forms of context as described in [out abridged guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619). Please study that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I can say for sure that there will be 2 one-dimensional and 1 two-dimensional irreducible representation of the group, but I find it difficult to answer what they look like